# Incorrect plotting of ramp sequence in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to plot a discrete [ramp sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramp_function) using Matlab, within the interval `[-10, 10]`.

This is my code:

```
function Ramp()
   rampseq(-10, 10);
end

function rampseq (n1, n2)
    n = (n1:1:n2);
    stem (n, pw(n));
end

function y = pw(n)
    if (n < 0)
        y = 0;
        return;
    else
        y = n;
        return;
    end
end
```

I define the behavior of the sequence in the `pw(n)` function (short form for 'piecewise'). Note that if `n < 0`, the output should be `0` or else if `n >= 0`, the output should be `n` itself. However, the plot turns out to be:

[image]

This isn't the ramp sequence as the Y-values are *not* `0` when `n < 0`, contrary to the behavior defined in the `pw(n)` function. Where am I going wrong? Is the `if` statement being skipped for some reason? The Command Window does not show any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the whole vector `n` into the `pw()` function. However, the `pw()` function then compares `n` to 0, which is a scalar.

You could adjust your `pw()` function to operate on vector inputs like this:

```
function y = pw(n)
    y = n;
    y(n < 0) = 0;
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how it works on vector inputs? What do the statement `y = n` and `y(n < 0) = 0` do? Isn't `n` a vector in this case too?

Comment: `y = n;` creates a vector identical to `n`. Then the `n < 0` part creates a logical (boolean) vector the same size as `n`, with value `true` where `n` is negative and `false` where `n` is non-negative. Matlab allows you to use this logical vector to index the vector `y`. Therefore, the `y(n < 0) = 0;` part assigns the value zero to all elements of `y` which are negative.